# Is there a way I can read packets from a pcap file into an array?

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, pcap

I am trying to build a new layer using scapy. I want to read a pcap file and store each packet in an array so that I can access all the information inside the packet using the index of the array.

Answer (score 2):

The scapy function that you're looking for is `rdpcap`

```
from scapy.all import *

packets = rdpcap('file.pcap')
packets[0].show()
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can read everywhere Scape is SUPER slow for pcap files >10MB. I made a couple of tools always using dpkt. Just to give you an idea. Having a 670MB file using dpkt splitting the specific bytes I need compared to full fletched scapy (reading raw packages (the fastest solution with scapy)) is:

dpkt needs 150s (6GB ram), scapy >750s (>10GB)

Comment: If you use `rdpcap()` and read it all in one go you're gonna get crazy results. But if you use `PcapReader` as an iterative you'll keep your ram (scapy)